# Creating docker repo in Artifactory with dedicated port, it says "SocketException: Permission denied"

Tags: artifactory

I am running Artifactory Pro (5.3.1), and was trying to use the docker registry functionality.

I created a docker repository, and gave it a port 5001 in the "Registry Port" config.
However, there's nothing running on port 5001 ("telnet localhost 5001" refuses to connect), and the logs show this:

```
[http-nio-8081-exec-7] [ERROR] (o.a.s.s.SshAuthServiceImpl:210) - Failed to start SSH server
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(AsynchronousServerSocketChannelImpl.java:162) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
    at org.apache.sshd.common.io.nio2.Nio2Acceptor.bind(Nio2Acceptor.java:66) ~[sshd-core-0.14.0.jar:0.14.0]
```

Any idea what could cause a "permission denied"? There's nothing running on that port (same error for any other port). It's on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Do you have a reverse proxy set with this port number that points it back to Artifactory? 
Do you have any firewall that might block the use of this port? 
Do you check the iptables to make sure this is open?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using and on what OS? there is a known issue with Java 7 which may cause this issue

Comment: Thanks Ariel - I had misunderstood how it maps ports (I was expecting 5001 port to be opened by the Artifactory service). I added the reverse proxy from server:5001 to localhost:8081 and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a misunderstanding how the docker registry worked with Artifactory.

The Artifactory service doesn't actually open the port assigned to the repo (5001 in this case), but the reverse proxy will listen on it and forward it (with the right X-forwarded-port) to the "normal" Artifactory service port (e.g. 8081).

After setting up the reverse proxy for it, it worked fine.